# Render Objects in Array in React HOC

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following React class:

```
import React from 'react';
import { withTranslation, WithTranslation } from 'react-i18next';

interface State {
    payouts: any;
}

interface Props extends WithTranslation {}

class Payout extends React.Component<Props, State> {
    constructor(props: Props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            payouts: [
                {id: 'PO_3', owner: 'OWNER1', amount: 89},
                {id: 'PO_3', owner: 'OWNER2', amount: 150},
                {id: 'PO_4', owner: 'OWNER3', amount: 135}
            ]
        };
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {
                    this.state.payouts.map((payout:any) => (
                        Object.entries(payout).map((val: any)=> (
                            <li>{val.id} - {val.owner} - {val.amount}</li>
                        ))
                    ))
                }
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default withTranslation()(Payout);
```

I am trying to render my state as a `<li>` element but I do net get any data shown.

Also would be `payouts: object[]` correct for the interface?

Comment: You don't need `Object.entries`/ the inner `map()` here, just output `payout.id` etc

Comment: I'm marking this as "unlikely to help future readers", given the nature of the issue and the chance this is being found by anybody who happens to make the same mistake (zero)

Comment: Please provide your extensive and complex calculations on how you got to zero. I'm really interested to see how you think that nobody ever in the future makes the same mistake to combine `map` and `Object.entries`.

Comment: Combining `map` and `Object.entries` is perfectly fine and I have done it many times. The mistake here was that you thought you needed an inner loop when you didn't (because `payout` is already the object you tried to access using `val`). Sure, it is possible that somebody else tries to do this and will find this question. That's why maybe nobody else will confirm my close vote.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I do net get any data shown

Calling `Object.entries` will give you the following return value:

```js
console.log(Object.entries({id: 'PO_4', owner: 'OWNER3', amount: 135}))
```

It's an array of arrays containing the property name and value. Of course these arrays don't have an `id`, `owner` or `amount` properties.

You don't want any of that. `payout` is already the object you want to access. Just remove that call:

```js
        return (
            <div>
                {
                    this.state.payouts.map((payout:any) => (
                        <li>{payout.id} - {payout.owner} - {payout.amount}</li>
                    ))
                }
            </div>
        );
```